# Is there a CentOS equivalent of the official ruby:2.2.0 docker image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I have just built a containerized ruby on rails application.  The application was originally running on CentOS servers, but my containerized version runs inside the ruby:2.2.0 docker [image](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/2d6449f03976ededa14be5cac1e9e070b74e4de4/2.2/Dockerfile) which is Debian based.

For the sake of simplicity it would be slightly better if I could have it run in a Redhat or CentOS based version of this docker image instead.  So is there an exact Redhat or CentOS based equivalent of the official ruby:2.2.0 docker image?

**Note:** I don't have any real need at the moment to run this inside of Redhat instead of Debian, so if the image I'm looking for doesn't exist then, to me, its not worth the time and effort of building one from scratch.

Comment: Not sure if this may be what your looking for but it looks like someone already installed/configured Ruby from a CentOS container. Take a look at this: https://github.com/volanja/docker-ruby2.2.0/blob/master/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ryekayo, after some editing of https://github.com/volanja/docker-ruby2.2.0/blob/master/Dockerfile I got a working version.